# Enumerate current running platform information in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cross-platform

I need to download a binary of a Go program from GitHub on a different platform using Python

In order to download a binary that matches the current platform, I need to translate the current platform information into a format that matches the [`GOARCH` and `GOOS` environment variables](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/go/build/syslist.go)

In NodeJS, I can do this very simply:

```js
function getArch() {
  switch (process.arch) {
    case 'x32': return '386'
    case 'x64': return 'amd64'
    case 'arm64': return 'arm64'
    case 'arm': return 'armv7'
  }

  throw new Error(`architecture "${process.arch}" is not supported`)
}

function getPlatform() {
  switch (process.platform) {
    case 'darwin': return 'darwin'
    case 'linux': return 'linux'
    case 'win32': return 'windows'
  }

  throw new Error(`platform "${process.platform}" is not supported`)
}
```

But for Python, it seems difficult to do this because the standard library [platform](https://docs.python.org/3/library/platform.html) does not have a good specification, and it does not list all possible return values for different platforms and architectures

For example, [`platform.architecture()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/platform.html#platform.architecture) will return `AMD64` for a Windows system with an `amd64` CPU, but `x86_64` for a Linux system with the same CPU, which makes it hard to have an elegant way to match each platform I need

Answer (score 0):

After consulting the source code of [platform](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/platform.py), I wrote the following code, which solves the problem in my case

```py
import platform

_ARCHITECTURE_DICT = {
    # For Windows, it uses PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE environment variable. Reference:
    # https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/wow64-implementation-details#environment-variables
    # https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/platform.py#L717-L727
    "Windows": {
        "AMD64": "amd64",
        "X86": "386",
        "ARM64": "arm64",
    },
    # For Unix-like system, it follows os.uname result. Reference:
    # https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uname
    "Linux": {
        "x86_64": "amd64",
        "i686": "386",
        "i386": "386",
        "aarch64": "arm64",
        "armv7l": "armv7",
    },
    "Darwin": {
        "x86_64": "amd64",
        "arm64": "arm64",
    },
}

_SYSTEM_DICT = {
    "Windows": "windows",
    "Linux": "linux",
    "Darwin": "darwin",
}


def _get_platform():
    uname = platform.uname()
    try:
        system = _SYSTEM_DICT[uname.system]
        architecture = _ARCHITECTURE_DICT[uname.system][uname.machine]
    except KeyError:
        raise RuntimeError(
            f"Unsupported platform: {uname.system} {uname.machine}"
        ) from None
    return system, architecture


GOOS, GOARCH = _get_platform()
```

**Update:** I found a third-party library [`py-cpuinfo`](https://github.com/workhorsy/py-cpuinfo) can get CPU architecture info elegantly, here is an example:

```py
import platform

from cpuinfo import get_cpu_info

_SYSTEM_MAP = {
    "Windows": "windows",
    "Linux": "linux",
    "Darwin": "darwin",
}

_ARCHITECTURE_MAP = {
    "X86_32": "386",
    "X86_64": "amd64",
    "ARM_7": "armv7",
    "ARM_8": "arm64",
}


def _get_platform():
    try:
        system = _SYSTEM_MAP[platform.system()]
        architecture = _ARCHITECTURE_MAP[get_cpu_info()["arch"]]
    except KeyError:
        raise RuntimeError(f"Unsupported platform: {platform.uname()!r}") from None
    return system, architecture


GOOS, GOARCH = _get_platform()
```